# res.send() is not giving response on POST request in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hy, I'm learning nodeJS but when do post using postman data is saving in db but not displaying response in POSTMAN. On postman just displaying **sending request...** .

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

// dbConnection
require('./mongo')
// Models
require('./model/Post')
// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json())

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Post = mongoose.model("Post")

// POST REQUEST
app.post('/posts', async (req, res)=>{
    // res.send(req.body)
    try{
        const post = new Post()
        post.title = req.body.title
        post.content = req.body.content
        data = await post.save()
        res.json(data)
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500)
    }
})


app.listen(8000, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is running on port:8000')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're even running on a port, it says here

```
    console.log('Server is running on port:8000')
})
```

All you do is console.log Server is running on Port 8000 with no back tick, therefore your not even running your server. This is why I think your Code is not working, test it out and see, if you get an error then you can debug from there. At least put some effort into debugging rather than immediately going on stack overflow. replace what you done with the port with this

```
// Create a variable called port and set it to your desired port
const port = 8000;
// Then hook it up to express.
console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

If the problem is still there then I think I have the solution to it

1. Check if you have mongoose and express installed
   (it's npm i mongoose express)
2. I don't think you're even connected to your mongoose server, try doing this

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

// dbConnection
require('./mongo')
// Models
require('./model/Post')
// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json())

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Post = mongoose.model("Post")
// Hook it up to res
const port = 8000

// POST REQUEST
app.post('/posts', async (req, res)=>{
    // res.send(req.body)
    try{
        const post = new Post()
        post.title = req.body.title
        post.content = req.body.content
        data = await post.save()
        res.json(data)
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500)
    }
})

// Mongoose Connection
mongoose
    .connect("your connection (it should be connection to application on mongo)", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: true
 })
 .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database");
 })
 .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
 });

app.listen(8000, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

Then once you've finished that, you established a connection to the mongodb server and should send the request to post

Comment: When I'm saying you're not running your server I meant your not running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `catch` block is executed. In this block, you only set the status of the response to 500 but you don't actually send the response to the client. That's why the Postman screen keeps blocking.

So, there are 2 things:

- you need to send something to the client
- you need to log the error to debug.

```
app.post('/posts', async (req, res)=>{
    // res.send(req.body)
    try{
        const post = new Post()
        post.title = req.body.title
        post.content = req.body.content
        data = await post.save()
        res.json(data)
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);// for debugging
        res.status(500).send("ERROR_SERVER"); // send something to client
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for your error, as I said in my old answer, running your tests would've worked, and showed you the error, however I have found the answer, I am assuming you have already found the solution (which is probably the same solution as mine) but if you haven't here's the problem.

## The problem

It's very simple, you're creating a variable for mongoose after you required mongoose `require('./mongo');    const mongoose = require('mongoose')` This is wrong as JavaScript and most programming languages read code line by line (if not then all) so change this up to be instead the following:

## Solution

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./mongo');
```

## Information

Create the variable before you require the package like so (in your code example):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./mongo');
```

## If you have more problems

If you do have more problems then try to reinstall/update the package dependency for mongoose as following:

```
yarn add mongoose
```

or

```
npm install mongoose
```

If you do still have problems after the only think I can ask you to do is to change the line of code when it says

```
require('./mongo');
```

to either

```
require('./{filename}'); // Whatever the actual filename is.
```

or:

```
require('./mongoose');
```

## Tips to improving your question

Even if my question doesn't work for your code make sure to paste the error message or the important parts of the error message into the question, otherwise this makes it hard to pinpoint what your error is. This makes it easier to find the solution for your code.